# Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка была на переднем плане?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы кнопка всегда была впереди всех, как на CSS... Сейчас ее закрывает нижний `LinearLayout`. Как это сделать?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/headImage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/stndHeight"
            android:background="#20ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/title1"
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle1"
                android:textColor="@color/titleEnableColor"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/title2"
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle2"
                android:textColor="@color/titleDisableColor"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/exchangePosition"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_click"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:src="@drawable/from"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconFrom" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/from"
                    android:id="@+id/tvFrom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    style="@style/mainTextStyle" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
                android:background="@color/vColor"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="2">
            </View>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:measureAllChildren="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:transitionGroup="false"
                android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:outlineProvider="bounds">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/smallIconSize"
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:background="@drawable/icon_click"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightPadding"
                    android:allowUndo="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/exchangePosition"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_click">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/to"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconFlyTo" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/to"
                    android:id="@+id/tvTo"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    style="@style/mainTextStyle"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
            android:background="@color/vColor"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconCalendar" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/vylet"
                android:id="@+id/tvDepart"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/lineHeight"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/separate_line" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/prilet"
                android:id="@+id/tvArrive"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
            android:background="@color/vColor"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:src="@drawable/passenger"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconPassenger" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/passengers"
                    android:id="@+id/tvPassengers"
                    style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="left">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/oldPassengers"
                            android:id="@+id/tvOldPass"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/textMargin"
                            style="@style/smallText" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/oldPassengersCount"
                            android:id="@+id/tvOldPassCount"
                            style="@style/smallText" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4"
                        android:gravity="left|center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/childPassengers"
                            android:id="@+id/tvChildPass"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/textMargin"
                            style="@style/smallText" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/childPassengersCount"
                            android:id="@+id/tvChildPassCount"
                            style="@style/smallText" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/babyPassengers"
                            android:id="@+id/textView10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/textMargin"
                            style="@style/smallText" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/babyPassengersCount"
                            android:id="@+id/textView13"
                            style="@style/smallText" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
            android:background="@color/vColor"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </View>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/iconsSize"
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:src="@drawable/classy"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconClass"
                android:background="@drawable/classy" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/busClass"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/lineHeight"
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:src="@drawable/separate_line"
                android:contentDescription="@string/iconLineSep" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/ecClass"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/mainTextStyle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
            android:background="@color/vColor"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
        </View>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/leftPadding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            style="@style/btnStyle"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Вам поможет `FrameLayout`. Как им пользоваться, вы можете найти в любом курсе уроков по `Android`

Comment: ок! Я добавил framelayout но проблема та же! ничего не изменилось!

Comment: добавьте разметку. Используете ли Вы RelativeLayout?

Comment: Нет! Не использую!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста! Из за маленькой проблемы нет времени на поиски видеоуроков по Frame

Comment: @Omuradil добавьте разметку- Вам подскажут

Comment: какую разметку?

Comment: xml-file в котором вы отрисовали эти элементы

Comment: Добавил разметку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сложная у Вас верстка. Вот как бы я отрисовал Ваш элемент.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_to"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/change"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Принцип, думаю, понятен.

Comment: то есть мой никак нельзя переделать...?

Comment: Сделал, как бэ помогло но верхний linearLayout на половину изчес ибо нижний Linear закрыл его нижнюю половину! как быть?

Comment: Сложная, это ещё очень мягко сказано.